# Why won't references file compile in TeX document?

Tags: bibtex, texpad

I'm using TexPad, and both files are in the same directory.  Here is my TeX file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}
HI

\bibliography{diy_biblio}


\end{document}
```

And here is diy_biblio.bib, created with Mendeley:

```
Automatically generated by Mendeley Desktop 1.14
Any changes to this file will be lost if it is regenerated by Mendeley.

BibTeX export options can be customized via Preferences -> BibTeX in Mendeley Desktop

@article{Menche2015,
author = {Menche, J. and Sharma, a. and Kitsak, M. and Ghiassian, S. D. and Vidal, M. and Loscalzo, J. and a.-L. Barabasi},
doi = {10.1126/science.1257601},
file = {:Users/hannahcatabia/Desktop/ordovas\_project/papers/menche/201502-19\_Science-Incomplete.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0036-8075},
journal = {Science},
number = {6224},
pages = {1257601--1257601},
title = {{Uncovering disease-disease relationships through the incomplete interactome}},
url = {http://www.sciencemag.org/cgi/doi/10.1126/science.1257601},
volume = {347},
year = {2015}
}
```

Comment: BTW: Delete the first 4 lines in the bib file. They will cause an error ...

Comment: Deleted them.  Still won't work.  Am I missing a \usepackage{} that I need for Bibtex or something?

Comment: bibliographies in bibtex format must be processed by bibtex into a `.bbl` file before they will appear in tex output.  they are *never* processed directly by latex.  (there are already quite a few questions on the topic on this site.)

Comment: Your tex file appears to be missing a `\bibliographystyle` directive. Without it, BibTeX won't do anything. (Check the `.blg` file to error messages...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted all your called packages which are not neccessary for the given problem.

But just a hint here: often the order of calling packages is important and a wrong order causes errors.  You called packages `babel` and `csquotes` after packages `hyperref`. Most packages should be called before `hyperref` is called.

That's the reason I used this two packages in my MWE too, in the correct order ...

You didn't cite any bib entry nor used command `\nocite{key}` to display not cited bib entrys (here entry `key`) or all (`\nocite{*}`) bib entrys in the bibliography.  Command `\nocite{*}` helps a lot to test the given `bib` file for faulty entrys ...

I used package `filecontents` to have `tex` code and `bib` file concatenated in one MWE. You do not need it for your work, it is only for testing purposes ...

You did not tell us which bibliography style you use, so I use the standard style `plain` here. Change it to that what you need.

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{Menche2015,
  author  = {Menche, J. and Sharma, a. and Kitsak, M. and Ghiassian, S. D. 
             and Vidal, M. and Loscalzo, J. and a.-L. Barabasi},
  doi     = {10.1126/science.1257601},
  file    = {:Users/hannahcatabia/Desktop/ordovas\_project/papers/menche/201502-19\_Science-Incomplete.pdf:pdf},
  issn    = {0036-8075},
  journal = {Science},
  number  = {6224},
  pages   = {1257601--1257601},
  title   = {{Uncovering disease-disease relationships through the incomplete interactome}},
  url     = {http://www.sciencemag.org/cgi/doi/10.1126/science.1257601},
  volume  = {347},
  year    = {2015},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}  % to visualise the typing area and margins

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,english=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}   % last package to be loaded here!

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys ==============================
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]